# Arrow function is considered unexpected token in React component using babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have this function in one of my react components.

```
export default class EventTags extends React.Component{
      showAll () => {
        this.setState({
          showAll: true,
          showBtn: false
        });
      }
}
```

When webpack watch hits it I get an unexpected token error on the arrow function. I have the transform-es2015-arrow-functions plugin enabled but it doesn't seem to change the outcome.

Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: showAll is a class' method?

Comment: I once got rid of it by adding `options : { plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]}` to the `babel-loader`

Comment: yes @Andrew_1510 that was it for me - dont forget `npm install babel-plugin-transform-class-properties --save`

Comment: For newer versions of Babel, I use this in .babelrc `{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need an equals sign when using class property initializers.

```
export default class EventTags extends React.Component {
  showAll = () => {
    this.setState({
      showAll: true,
      showBtn: false
    });
  };
}
```

- Ensure you have the [transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) Babel transform enabled
- Unlike class methods, class property initializers should be followed by semicolons

Babel's docs on [arrow functions in ES6 React components](https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/07/07/react-on-es6-plus.html#arrow-functions) shows longer examples.

Comment: It's weird. I'm getting an unexpected token on the first = now.

Comment: Do you have the [transform-class-properties transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) enabled in your Babel config?

Comment: Boom. This has me moving forward. Thank you very much. Still learning quite a bit about babel and ES6

Comment: @Ross you don't use arrow functions, nor `=` in a class' method declariation at all

Comment: if I don't use it then "this" is undefined when trying to set the state of the react component. If this is not the correct way then what is?

Comment: This is the recommended way, you've got it. @baao The OP wants the context to be the component instance when the property is passed as a callback.

Comment: Babel Doc link has 404'd

Comment: @KarlTaylor Thanks for the heads up. I fixed the link.

Comment: @bambam Can you explain further what you mean by your comment?

Answer (score -3):

You need to assign the arrow function, below is the correct syntax for creating a named arrow function.

```
const showAll = () => {
  this.setState({
    showAll: true,
    showBtn: false
  });
}
```

Comment: No `const`. My interpretation of the question was that this was a property initializer inside a class.

Comment: @RossAllen Fair enough, OP should have provided more code, IMO.

Comment: Agreed, but the first sentence does say "I have this function in one of my react components."

Comment: I'm realizing that now