# Async named arrow fucntion Error 'Unexpected token'

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, create-react-app

I am learning React, using create-react-app. There was a situation that Google could not solve. Where am I wrong? How to fix it?

I don’t understand why my code works on codepen.io.
https://codepen.io/VaskaDeGame/pen/zQzeGM
But does not work on the local machine :(

```
const getResource = async (url) => {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    return res.json();
};
getResource('https://swapi.co/api/people/1/')
    .then((body) => {
        console.log(body);
    });
```

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Z:/projects/vdg_swapi/src/index.js: Unexpected token (10:32)
   8 | );
   9 | 
> 10 | const getResource = async (url) => {
     |                                 ^
  11 |     const res = await fetch(url);
  12 |     return res.json();
  13 | };
    at Parser.pp.raise (Z:\projects\vdg_swapi\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\location.js:22:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (Z:\projects\vdg_swapi\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\util.js:89:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseAsyncArrowFromCallExpression (Z:\projects\vdg_swapi\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:369:47)
    at Parser.parseAsyncArrowFromCallExpression (Z:\projects\vdg_swapi\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babylon\lib\plugins\flow.js:389:20)
    at Parser.pp.parseSubscripts (Z:\projects\vdg_swapi\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:320:21)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (Z:\projects\vdg_swapi\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:287:15)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (Z:\projects\vdg_swapi\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:257:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (Z:\projects\vdg_swapi\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:188:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (Z:\projects\vdg_swapi\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:165:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (Z:\projects\vdg_swapi\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:128:19)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (Z:\projects\vdg_swapi\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babylon\lib\plugins\flow.js:460:20)
    at Parser.pp.parseVar (Z:\projects\vdg_swapi\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\statement.js:601:24)
    at Parser.pp.parseVarStatement (Z:\projects\vdg_swapi\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\statement.js:424:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseStatement (Z:\projects\vdg_swapi\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\statement.js:120:19)
    at Parser.parseStatement (Z:\projects\vdg_swapi\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babylon\lib\plugins\flow.js:30:22)
    at Parser.pp.parseBlockBody (Z:\projects\vdg_swapi\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\statement.js:529:21)
 @ multi main
errors @ client:47
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "swapi",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "0.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Node version: v12.2.0

What is interesting, if you run this code in Google Chrome browser, then it will run without errors.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>VDG SWAPI</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/slate/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>
      getResource = async (url) => {
        const res = await fetch(url);
        return res.json();
      };
      getResource('https://swapi.co/api/people/1/')
              .then((body) => {
                console.log(body);
              });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code is fine in its own context, so it must be a problem with where you've got it.  I'm guessing you're trying to use this as a class method and the parser is thrown off by the `const`.  If my guess is incorrect, please publish your entire class here.  See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495306/arrow-function-is-considered-unexpected-token-in-react-component-using-babel

Comment: In fact, this question has little to do with React. As I studied, I ran into fetch and decided to try. Use an empty index.js with the above mentioned code.

Comment: You've likely forgot some brace or parenthesis somewhere, the syntax is fine, unless you post the code directly above the one we can see, there is little we can do to help.

Comment: The fact is that this is all the code) I have a clean create react app installed and this code is written.

Comment: Looks like it does not understand ES6. Are you using a current node version?

Comment: Node version: v12.2.0

Comment: Try running  `const test = async x => x; test(1).then(console.log, console.error)` in it's own file. My `node 12.2.0` successfully logs `1`. If you get the same result, it means you likely have a syntax problem somewhere above `getResource`.

Comment: @user633183 Unexpected token (13:23) > 
`13 |     const test = async x => x; test(1).then(console.log, console.error);`

Comment: @user633183 
I used clean index.js files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see you have a very old version of what looks like the `create-react-app`. The dependencies in one I created 2 months ago are

```
"react": "^16.8.3",
"react-dom": "^16.8.3",
"react-scripts": "2.1.5",
```

These dependencies in turn depend on specific version of the babel transpiller. Could you check your package-lock.json to see what version of babel you are using? I you are using below 7 you may want to either upgrade your dependencies or add the arrow function support. see https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions